# MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object] with findOne mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code where I am finding a monitor in the database with these queries

```js
        const monitorfind = await monitorschema.findOne({ Price: { $lte: Number(reqbody.price) } }, {Size: {$gte: Number(reqbody.size - 8)}}, {hz: {$gte: Number(reqbody.hz - 25)}}, {Resolution: {$gte: Number(reqbody.res)}}, {ResponseTime: {$lte: Number(reqbody.ms +4)}})
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
throw new MongooseError('Callback must be a function, got ' + callback);
          ^

MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
    at Function.Model.$handleCallbackError (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4924:11)
    at Function.findOne (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2248:19)
    at C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\routes\monitors.js:23:49
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\pickitly_web_main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain `exec()` function after `findOne`. It is needed if we want to use `async-await`. Changing query to following should work:

```
const monitorfind = await monitorschema.findOne({
  Price: { $lte: Number(reqbody.price) },
  Size: {$gte: Number(reqbody.size - 8)},
  hz: {$gte: Number(reqbody.hz - 25)},
  Resolution: {$gte: Number(reqbody.res)},
  ResponseTime: {$lte: Number(reqbody.ms +4)}
}).exec()
```

Reference: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/promise

In case you are using older version of mongoose (<5), you will have to pass callback function as second param to `findOne` as suggested in [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528351/2235057).

Answer (score 1):

I think your `reqbody` is wrong pattern.right pattern is `req.body`.but you use any middleware `function` for passing data at time use code otherwise you can use `req.body` for your code.

try this

```
const conditions = {
    Price: { $lte: Number(reqbody.price) },
    Size: {$gte: Number(reqbody.size - 8)},
    hz: {$gte: Number(reqbody.hz - 25)},
    Resolution: {$gte: Number(reqbody.res)},
    ResponseTime: {$lte: Number(reqbody.ms +4)}
}

monitorschema.findOne(conditions, function (err, monitor) {

    console.log(monitor) //If matching any data it is show here 

});
```